# Which rifle does the highest DPS with only headshots?

Tags: halo-4

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Mid-range weapon balance](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/92357/mid-range-weapon-balance)

Which rifle does the highest DPS (damage per second) with only headshots?

Between:

- Battle Rifle
- DMR
- Carbine